# Issues deploying vite app with three.js import to netlify

Tags: javascript, html, css, three.js

Like the title says below is the error. I've tried looking for other similar issues people had but still nothing that helps me understand why or what to change to fix this issue. Thank you for any help I truly appreciate it. The app works fine locally if that matters.

[vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "three" from "/opt/build/repo/main.js".
9:03:37 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
9:03:37 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
9:03:37 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`
9:03:37 PM: error during build:
9:03:37 PM: Error: [vite]: Rollup failed to resolve import "three" from "/opt/build/repo/main.js".
9:03:37 PM: This is most likely unintended because it can break your application at runtime.
9:03:37 PM: If you do want to externalize this module explicitly add it to
9:03:37 PM: `build.rollupOptions.external`

Deploying site expecting it to deploy properly but it is not

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.